# why I got error "Could not retrieve endpoint rangs" when I run sstableloader?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I used the sstableloader many times successfully, but I got the following error:

```
[root@localhost pengcz]# /usr/local/cassandra/bin/sstableloader -u user -pw password -v -d 172.21.0.131 ./currentdata/keyspace/table
Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:338)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:156)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(ByteBufferUtil.java:543)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.CollectionSerializer.readValue(CollectionSerializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MapSerializer.deserializeForNativeProtocol(MapSerializer.java:101)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MapSerializer.deserializeForNativeProtocol(MapSerializer.java:30)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.CollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.compose(AbstractType.java:68)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.UntypedResultSet$Row.getMap(UntypedResultSet.java:287)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromSchemaNoTriggers(CFMetaData.java:1833)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromThriftCqlRow(CFMetaData.java:1126)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:330)
    ... 2 more
```

I don't know whether this error is relative to one of cluster nodes' linux crash?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running different version sstable loader than the version of your cluster? Looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9324 if using the 2.1 loader on 2.0 cluster.

Answer (score 0):

**/usr/local/cassandra/bin/sstableloader -u user -pw password -v -d 172.21.0.131 ./currentdata/keyspace/table** into this command as mention by you backup dir is as ./currentdata/keyspace/table, change the parent directory name of table dir to the keyspace name into which you are restoring, at the place of keyspace and also change the name of table dir as these two are cassandra preserved delimeters and sstableloader consider the parent dir of backup directory(here parent->keyspace and backup-dir->table) as a keyspace name, So it should be same as the keyspace name into which you are restoring the data. Apart from this please make sure your table name and keyspace name should not be as cassandra preserved delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but I'm posting the answer here for posterity. It looks like you're hitting [CASSANDRA-10700](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10700).

**TL;DR** - When sstableloader tries to read the schema, it fails when it comes across a dropped collections column.

The problem only exists in the sstableloader utility and you can easily workaround it by getting a copy from Cassandra 2.1.13+ as [documented here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207920393). Cheers!